# How do I know the Description of the service that is running in remote machine in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicecontroller

I know the service that is running using

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
ServiceController.GetServices(DropDownListMachineName.SelectedValue))
```

but ServiceController does not contain any method or property to get the Description of the service.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) suggests:

```
ManagementObject wmiService;
wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + sc.ServiceName + "'");
wmiService.Get();
Console.WriteLine("    Description:     {0}", wmiService["Description"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

[ServiceController.GetServices Method ()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y721)